# Implementing UIView on top of NSView for porting from iOS to Mac OSX

Tags: ios, macos, porting

I'd like to port my app to Mac OSx.  in that vein, I'd like to create a class called "UIView" as an extension of NSView ..  is this doable?   Other than the coordinate system, is there anything I need to be worried about?

I assume CALayer and CoreAnimation are mostly the same.     Other classes are UIImage and UIImageView, UIButton, etc.

Has anyone attempted this yet?

Comment: there are enough differences in implementation that apple thought it worth separating them, whilst keeping foundation classes the same across platforms. it may be possible using preprocessor macros to pull in different code depending on platform target, but it will leave you with code that is very difficult to maintain. I would say its not worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second MCannon’s advice: you preprocessor macros, or abstract your classes behind an opaque class object, but I strongly advise against creating a new `UIView` class inheriting from `NSView` on Mac.